# hot to notify viewmodel property form model so that property value reflect in view

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {   
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

This the base class which implement INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public class LogActivity : ViewModelBase
{
    private string messageLog;

    public string MessageLog
    {
        get
        {
            return messageLog;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != messageLog)
            {
                messageLog = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("MessageLog");
            }
        }
    }  

}
```

This is my viewmodel class

```
public class SingleMessageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
 private LogActivity messagelog;

public SingleMessageViewModel()
    {

        messagelog = new LogActivity();
}   


public LogActivity MessageLog
    {
        get
        {
            return messagelog;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != messagelog)
            {
                messagelog = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("MessageLog");
            }
        }
    }  
 }
```

This is my view where the above property bind to:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TxtLog" Text="{Binding LogMessage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
```

I want to use this property in one of my model class and send the notification to viewmodel about the property change so that It can bind to view given above.

Request you all to provide me some help on this. Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: Poor-quality question, riddled with typos.  I would downvote it if I had enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

This Code:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TxtLog" Text="{Binding LogMessage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
```

Needs to be:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TxtLog" Text="{Binding MessageLog.MessageLog, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
```

Note the Binding, you are binding to a property within LogActivity and it needs to be pointed to it properly.

Comment: And as a side note maybe try renaming the first class something other than the string you're binding to... looks/feels odd.